# Assosiative array and display the results with foreach statement table

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my code and works fine but when i display the foreach statement it's messed up!

```
$people= array(

array(
    "name" => "Jennifer Kimbers",
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "state" => "Washington"),

array(
    "name" => "Rodney Hutchers",
    "email" => "def@gmail.com",
    "city" => "Los Angeles",
    "state" => "California"),

);


    echo "<table>";
    echo "<th>FullName</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>City</th>";
    echo "<th>State</th>";

foreach ($people as $person)
{
    foreach ($person as $key=>$values)
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$values</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
}
```

My question it's how with the foreach statement i can display the results organized
for example: `<th>Fullname<th>` and below that only the name `Jennifer Kimbers` and below that `Rodney Hutchers`,
After that next to the `<th>Email<th>` and below that `abc@gmail.com` and below that `def@gmail.com` ..... etc
I have searched this forum or the internet didn't find anything 
Thank you for your time

Comment: You don't have `<tr>` for the first row before the loop and you don't close the table `</table>`. And you want to open and close the row in the first foreach not the inner one.

Comment: yes i know for `css` purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness, there is no need to `echo` everything when you are mixing php with HTML.

```
    //not sure what is above this, so will just end it here.
    ?>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>FullName</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>

    <?php foreach ($people as $person) : ?>
      <tr>    
        <?php foreach ($person as $key => $values) : ?>
            <td><?php echo $values; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Create complete and valid code. Don't leave out `<tr></tr>`, solve the CSS issue in another way.

======

Alternative way of doing things. The code may look a little more complicated but it is way easier to maintain. In case you want to add zipcode for example, all you have to do is change the `$fields` array. Everything else will adapt.

```
$fields = ['name','email','city','state'];
?>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach($fields as $field): ?>
          <th><?php echo ucfirst($field); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>

   <?php  foreach ($people as $person) : ?> 
      <tr>    
         <?php foreach ($fields as $field) :  ?>
            <td> <?php echo $person[$field]; ?> </td>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </table>
```

Comment: when i run your code, tha table displays value value value... the user DE_ brings me the result that i want .. but yes with one foreach not two

Comment: You are correct. Forgot the echo the value. It was more about the formatting than about the code logic. Personally I would use a different approach. Will update the answer with that soon.

Comment: How you would approach it? You mean writting less code ?

Comment: little more compact maybe, but the bigger gain here is maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The table rows need to be in the first loop.

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>FullName</th>";
echo "<th>Email</th>";
echo "<th>City</th>";
echo "<th>State</th>";

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo "<tr>";    

    foreach ($person as $key=>$values) {
        echo "<td>$values</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```